# Elasticsearch: Show which analyzer was used in analyze api

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to figure out how elasticsearch analyzers work exactly and I'm using the `_analyze` api e.g. `_analyze?text=http://www.google.com`
Does elasticsearch provide the information of which analyzer was used?
Although the information provided is step by step of the analysis performed, some analyzers may produce the same output so instead of trying to force a different output in order to check which analyzer was used, I was wondering if this can be provided by the api.

I'm using `ElasticSearch 1.7.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not give you the analyzer being used because it's supposed to be specified either in the command itself with `?analyzer=` or using the analyzer from the index or from the field that's being used in the command.

Also, there are rules related to which analyzer is being used and you should be able to determine from these which one is actually applied: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_controlling_analysis.html#_default_analyzers